# Admin login is not working, customer login is working - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, admin-login

I have a first install of the opensource 2.3 version with demo data.
Everything seems to be working in the public facing pages, but I can't login as Admin. The demo customer login is fine.

I don't get anything in the error logs, the message returned is "The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later."

The user isn't locked.

It seems to blow up in the function at line 568 of

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php
 function authenticate($username, $password)
```

But i'm not sure how to follow it after that.

Comment: first check in your database "admin_user" table, username is there or not, if there then reset the password by direct query in DB, which is fast way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new user with this command:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=test --admin-password=test456 --admin-email=test@oscprofessionals.com --admin-firstname=Test --admin-lastname=User
```

Then Your User Name will be : **test** and Password will be : **test456**

Then You can easily loggedin in Backend.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I guess I was trying to do an admin login on the customer login page.
Carry over from working with drupal.
Thanks.

Comment: Okay, But this will help you to solve this problem for next time.

Comment: Yes, I learned a lot about how the admin user is created.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to login as an admin on the customer login page.
I did a wizard install which redirected me to the correct login page and everything works.